# flink sink to parquet file with AvroParquetWriter is not writing data to file

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, parquet-mr

I am trying to write a parquet file as sink using AvroParquetWriter. The file is created but with 0 length (no data is written). am I doing something wrong ? couldn't figure out what is the problem

```
import io.eels.component.parquet.ParquetWriterConfig
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericData, GenericRecord}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.{ParquetFileWriter, ParquetWriter}
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata.CompressionCodecName

import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._

object Tester extends App {
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  def now = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val path = new Path(s"/tmp/test-$now.parquet")
  val schemaString = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/request_schema.avsc")).mkString
  val schema: Schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString)
  val compressionCodecName = CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY
  val config = ParquetWriterConfig()
  val genericReocrd: GenericRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema)
  genericReocrd.put("name", "test_b")
  genericReocrd.put("code", "NoError")
  genericReocrd.put("ts", 100L)
  val stream = env.fromElements(genericReocrd)
  val writer: ParquetWriter[GenericRecord] = AvroParquetWriter.builder[GenericRecord](path)
    .withSchema(schema)
    .withCompressionCodec(compressionCodecName)
    .withPageSize(config.pageSize)
    .withRowGroupSize(config.blockSize)
    .withDictionaryEncoding(config.enableDictionary)
    .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE)
    .withValidation(config.validating)
    .build()

  writer.write(genericReocrd)
  stream.addSink{r =>
    writer.write(r)
  }
  env.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't close the `ParquetWriter`. This is necessary to flush pending elements to disk. You could solve the problem by defining your own `RichSinkFunction` where you close the `ParquetWriter` in the `close` method:

```
class ParquetWriterSink(val path: String, val schema: String, val compressionCodecName: CompressionCodecName, val config: ParquetWriterConfig) extends RichSinkFunction[GenericRecord] {
  var parquetWriter: ParquetWriter[GenericRecord] = null

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    parquetWriter = AvroParquetWriter.builder[GenericRecord](new Path(path))
      .withSchema(new Schema.Parser().parse(schema))
      .withCompressionCodec(compressionCodecName)
      .withPageSize(config.pageSize)
      .withRowGroupSize(config.blockSize)
      .withDictionaryEncoding(config.enableDictionary)
      .withWriteMode(ParquetFileWriter.Mode.OVERWRITE)
      .withValidation(config.validating)
      .build()
  }

  override def close(): Unit = {
    parquetWriter.close()
  }

  override def invoke(value: GenericRecord, context: SinkFunction.Context[_]): Unit = {
    parquetWriter.write(value)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well. The file is created but the data is not flushed to the file. I think because I am using a stream which is infinite so it doesn't end hence the `close` method is not called

Comment: But then at some point it should have written enough records to fill up the internal buffers and flush it. It can only happen if your infinite stream does not produce enough data.

Comment: I haven't checked but maybe one can trigger the flushing explicitly and call it every so and so many records.